# How to conditionally pass criteria in scope

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am using mongoid 3.15.
I have a model called 'Building' with properties: name, province, district, street. I want to create a scope (or class method), called 'in' for example. It should accept a hash criteria that contains one of (or all of) 'province', 'district' and 'street' and
- if one of them provided, then it searches by one of those properties
- if two or more of them provided, then it should find buildings that match all criteria

Building model

```
    class Building
      include Mongoid::Document
      store_in collection: 'buildings'

      field :name, type: String
      field :province, type: String
      field :district, type: String
      field :street, type: String

      #scope/class method to search by province/district/street
      def self.in(crit = {})
        #see the logic below
      end
    end
```

I tried with 2 solutions but none of them works:

```
      def self.in(crit = {})
        where(province: crit[:province]) if crit[:province]
        where(district: crit[:district]) if crit[:district]
        where(street: crit[:street]) if crit[:street]
      end
```

this works if only provide 'province' or 'district' or 'street', but not two or all of them because the later 'where' wins

and

```
      def self.in(crit = {})
        query = where(province: crit[:province])
        query = query.where(district: crit[:district]) if crit[:district]
        query = query.where(street: crit[:street]) if crit[:street]
      end
```

with this you must always provide 'province'

Please help me to make it work or provide me another solution

Thank you and sorry for my English

**Combine drinor's answer with using scope style, the problem is solved:**

```
    scope :in, -> (crit = {}) {
        conditions = []
        conditions.push { :province => crit[:province] } if crit[:province]
        conditions.push { :district => crit[:district] } if crit[:district]
        conditions.push { :street => crit[:street] } if crit[:street]
        where( "$and" => conditions ) unless conditions.empty?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
def self.in(crit = {})
    conditions = []
    conditions.push { :province => crit[:province] } if crit[:province]
    conditions.push { :district => crit[:district] } if crit[:district]
    conditions.push { :street => crit[:street] } if crit[:street]
    where( "$and" => conditions ) unless conditions.empty?
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much drinor. It works as I expected. Just one more thing, is it possible to make it skips 'where' if crit is empty?

Comment: If conditions is empty, it returns an error. So you can add 'unless conditions.empty?', in which case scope will returns nil.

Comment: Then it will return error for call: `Buildings.in({}).count` because `in({})` return nil. Can we make it return buildings in all locations?

Comment: Yes you can use: `conditions.empty? ? all : where( "$and" => conditions )`

Comment: I figured it out. If we use scope-style it will skip the filter and not return nil.

Answer (score 0):

You could split conditions into scopes and use condition inside each scope.

```
scope :province, -> province { where(province: province) if province.present? }
scope :district, -> district { where(province: district) if district.present? }
scope :strict, -> street { where(province: street) if street.present? }
```

Check out the [Active Record scopes vs class methods](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) article and "Scopes are always chainable" section for more details.